# FabricJs Canvas 'Mouse:over' event not working

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to listern for mouse:over events on FabricJS(**version:1.4.0**) canvas, but it seems not to work as i expect. Here is the snippet

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {selection: false});

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 120,
    top: 30,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    angle: 20,
    name: 'Rectangle',
    hoverCursor: 'pointer'
});

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();

$('.upper-canvas').mouseover(function (e)
{
     
     if(e.target !== null)
     {
        if(e.target.name === 'Rectangle')
       {
          e.target.set('fill', 'red');
          canvas.renderAll();
          console.log('mouse:over', e.target.name);
       }
     } 

});

$('.upper-canvas').mouseout(function (e)
{
    if(e.target !== null){
      e.target.set('fill', 'green');
      canvas.renderAll();
      console.log('mouse:out', e.target.name);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Added mouse:out event too and canvas.renderAll() function to re-draw the canvas.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem. It might be because fabric js puts an element over the canvas. You want to listen to the events on that element. `.upper-canvas`

Comment: What do you mean to listen on .upper-canvas ?

Comment: Fabric js puts a canvas element over the original canvas element with the class `upper-canvas`. It blocks the click events from working on the element under it.

Comment: How do i attach the events to the element under upper-canvas ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I might be leading you in the wrong direction. When I read their docs. The solution you have should work. http://fabricjs.com/hovering

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to the version 1.4.0 because if i change to version 1.5.0, everything seems to work and my concern is that our production environment is set to use 1.4.0.

Comment: Yeah I tried with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js and it works fine.

Comment: @ChrisHemmens _It might be because fabric js puts an element over the canvas. You want to listen to the events on that element. .upper-canvas_ - this is exactly what fabric.js does. I'm not sure which problem you're referring to.

Comment: @shkaper I made something before with Fabric and I had to resort to using the upper-canvas element to handle some of my mouse events. That was a long time ago though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [1.5.0 changelog](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150):

> Add "mouse:over" and "mouse:out" canvas events (and corresponding
>   "mouseover", "mouseout" object events).

There are literally no such events prior to 1.5.0.

Comment: @Xris , again, it won't work with 1.4.0. There are no `over`/`out` events in 1.4.0. According to the Changelog, those events were added in 1.5.0. If you can't use 1.5.0 for whatever reason - you'll have to 1) implement your own events, or 2) look for the commits in 1.5.0 that add those events and patch the version you're running.

Comment: Any idea how i would implement these events ? I have tried to upgrade to version 1.5.0 and everthing broke

Comment: @Xris [This](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/commit/8d8cd16f6c3045b414ce150fa2270b364be9fa96#diff-e043717eeb1106354d4cb8a776e53767R7918) might help. Although in my opinion, it's always better to upgrade (and fix whatever's broken) in the long run.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, i am going to try to see if i can add those two missing events. Once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I could come up with for 1.4.0. I'd advise using different version.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {selection: false});

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 120,
    top: 30,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    angle: 20,
    name: 'Rectangle',
    hoverCursor: 'pointer'
});

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();

$('.upper-canvas').mouseover(function(e){
  rect.set('fill','red');
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$('.upper-canvas').mouseout(function(e){
  rect.set('fill','green');
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```